# Focus on scroll section of html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a page consisting of three div sections.

```
<div id="header">
<!--header html goes here-->
</div>
<div id="body" class="page-body">
<!--main html goes here-->
</div>
<div id="footer">
<!--footer html goes here-->
</div>
```

and my css is

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.page-body
{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

The problem with this is if user pressed `PgDn` or `down arrow` key then the page doesn't scroll down. In order for page to scroll down through keyboard the user has to first click on `page-body` `div` section and then the key presses work.

I have tried using `autofocus` tag on the page-body div or writing `document.getElementById('page-body').focus()` on load, but nothing seems to work. How can I get keyboard to work as soon as page loads without having to click on the section? I would prefer solution without javascript since my page doesn't really need it, but if I have to I am ok with javascript solution too.

Comment: Can you produce a minimum working sample?  I copied/pasted your code into a sandbox, there are no scroll bars to speak of: https://jsbin.com/jifabam/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: very hard hard to tell without a sample, but you can try to add a hidden input field in your .page-body and add the autofocus attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LattyS has provided valid code snippet and also valid js answer, however if you would like to get this done without using js then all you have to do is use [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) attribute with [autofocus](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_autofocus.asp) attribute.

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page-body {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <!--header html goes here-->
  Header
</div>
<div id="body" class="page-body" tabIndex="1" autofocus>
  <p>123</p>
  <p>123 123</p>
  <p>123 123 123</p>
  <p>123 123 123 123</p>
  <p>123 123 123 123 123</p>
  <p>123 123 123 123</p>
  <p>123 123 123</p>
  <p>123 123</p>
  <p>123</p>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <!--footer html goes here-->
  Footer
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there, just add a positive [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) attribute on your div. But you should know that in term of accessibility it is not a very good practice.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('body').focus();
};
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page-body {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <!--header html goes here-->
</div>
<div id="body" class="page-body" tabIndex="1">
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <!--footer html goes here-->
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please add a comment that same thing can be achieved simply by using autofocus on the page-body div tag? This way one doesn't need javascript and the solution can be achieved by simple html code. autofocus combined with tab index solves the problem.